# Grep searching for words by letter

Tags: grep

I'm searching through a file of people that is structured like below

John Smith 555-555-5555 Harvard Square, Boston

I'm interested in finding all the LAST names that start with the a certain letter.  I've tried using "grep \

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `awk` instead of `grep` e.g. to find lines whose second space-separated field starts with letter `S`

```
awk '$2 ~ /^S/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grep` with a Regex pattern:

```
grep -P "(?<=^[A-Za-z]+\\s)A"
```

This should match all entrys with the last name beginning with A.

---

### Regex explanation

The **Lookbehind** `(?<=text)` checks whether `text` occurs before the actually searched pattern. I use it to skip the first name, which is given by `^[A-Za-z]+\\s`, meaning beginning of line (`^`), then at least one letter, no matter if captital or not, then a space (`\\s`). After the lookbehind, the actually matched pattern stands, in this case the capital letter A.

Comment: Try `grep -P "^[A-Za-z]+\\sA"` instead. It might work without the  lookbehind

Comment: No still doesn't

Comment: Do you actually append the file name?